# Error while entering a text in a input box in tricentis Tosca

Tags: tosca

I'm trying to add a text into input box in tricentis tosca. But the webpage throws an error something like :

*Message from webpage: 
The value "[123456, function(callback/*, thisArg/*] { 
VarT,K.....

I treid using SENDKEYS and USERSIMULATION even then i couldn't avoid this error.

Comment: Can you please share the full error message? And also what you have entered in the Value column of TestStepValue?

Comment: The error message is very huge. it seems like a java script message. I'm entering 12345601 as text in it. However, it throws error for any text I enter in it. I tried with different texts.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you enter the text manually? Is the Application under Test is being actively developed? This looks to me more like a debug code accidentally left out. Interesting thing is that you entered "12345601" but the error message says "123456". Can you check if the value entered in Tosca is plaintext or have other characters appended?